# Add Catalog to an Existing Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an existing Linked Server with a few catalogs... how can I add another, existing database/catalog to this linked server?

For Example, my object explorer looks like this:

Linked Servers

- Providers
- DB4\PRODUCTION
- DB4_LINK

  - Catalogs

    - System Catalogs
    - MyDatabase
    - MyOtherDatabase

How can I add yet another database that already exists to DB4_LINK?

EDIT: I'm trying to add an *existing* database to this linked server entry.

Comment: I would restate the problem as "How do I make an existing database, which already exists but doesn't show in this list, appear?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by sending dynamic SQL via the linked server:

```
EXEC DB4_LINK.master..sp_executesql N'CREATE DATABASE foo;';
```

Of course this requires that you have the permissions to do so, and it's a simplistic command assuming that the default settings are fine - you may want to customize the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

Comment: I should have been clearer - I'm trying to add an existing database though... would I still use the "CREATE DATABASE" command? I'll update my post

Comment: How about disconnecting and reconnecting the entire Object Explorer tree? Are you sure you (and/or the linked server security credentials) have access to see the new database?

Comment: I haven't added anything to this linked server though. The DB4_LINK contains 5 databases... my server has about 20 databases total.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the other 15 may be hidden because you (or the login the linked server connects as) lacks the permissions necessary to see all 20 databases.

Comment: Oh wow. I think I misunderstood how linked servers works. If I create a link between two servers, that list of catalogs will show ALL databases for which I have access?

Comment: You were correct. My user didn't have access to the DB I was trying to "add" to my DB4_LINK. After granting access, then refreshing, the DB showed up in DB4_LINK. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkB how did you grant the user access to the DB you were trying to "add"?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming there are existing Catalogs (databases) already being shown (which is the case in your question), the most likely thing that is preventing another database on that same linked server from appearing is Permissions.

Right-click on the server-to-link-to and do "Script Linked Server as" then CREATE to New Query Window... look at the sp_addlinkedsrvlogin call and note the rmtuser (remote user).  This is the user that you needs access to the database that you want to appear in the Catalogs.

Go to the server-to-link-to (under Security / Logins) and adjust that login's permissions (via Properties) to include the missing db. (Check the perms that the login has to the dbs that do appear in the Catalog... you can use those specific perms as a reference)